# PartialView relacionamentos asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Estou tendo dificuldade para criar a logica de cadastro de *models* que tem relacionamento entre eles. Um existe somente a referencia, porém no outro a referencia é do tipo *List*<>.

Criei uma *partialview* contendo somente o campo, porém, não consigo fazer com que a tela seja mostrada para realizar o cadastro. Já foram mostrados vários erros: nullreferenceexception, o model é do 'x' mas espera do tipo 'y', etc.

Já estou a dois dias nessa tarefa!!

Alguém poderia me ajudar a montar a logica do cadastro? Digo, inclusive as *views* e *partials* *views*??

Model 1

```
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Campo2")]
    public string Campo2 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "MeuEnum")]
    public MeuEnum MeuEnum { get; set; }
    public IList<Model2> Model2 { get; set; } = new List<Model2>();
```

Model 2

```
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "MeuOutroEnum")]
    public MeuOutroEnum Tipo { get; set; }
    public virtual Model1 Model1 { get; set; }
```

Minha *view Create*

```
//Os campos do model1....

@Html.Partial("_PartialModel2", Model.Model2)
```

Minha *partial view*

```
@model List<MeuProjeto.Presentation.Web.Modelos.Model2>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => item.MeuOutroEnum, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.Tipo, new SelectList(Model[0].Tipo))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Tipo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei alguns erros no seu código:

1. Dentro do foreach da PartialView, o objeto `item` é do tipo `Model2` e esse tipo não contém uma propriedade chamada `MeuOutroEnum`, acredito que esteja tentando usar a propriedade de `Model2` que é desse tipo, ou seja, a propriedade `Tipo` (da mesma forma como você fez no `DropDownListFor`;
2. No `DropDownListFor`, também existe um erro no segundo parâmetro, ao criar uma nova `SelectList` com apenas um parâmetro, esse parâmetro deve implementar a interface `IEnumerable` e `Model[0].Tipo` é um Enum que não implementa. Se a ideia é criar um DropDown com todos os Enums existentes de MeuOutroEnum você pode usar os seguintes métodos para transformar seu Enum em um IEnumerable:

   Enum.GetValues(typeof(MeuOutroEnum)).Cast())

O que eu consegui executar aqui sem erros foi (sem considerar o CSS):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => item.Tipo)
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.Tipo,
                new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(MeuOutroEnum)).Cast<MeuOutroEnum>()))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Tipo,"")
        </div>
    </div>
}
```